# call function over list

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

I'm trying to learn python and have gotten way over my head on this problem.

I have a a nested list like so, with a mixture of fractions and integers in the numbers:

```
results = [
{
    "date": "2016-06-30",
    "item1": [
        "9/2",
        "4",
    ],
    "item2": [
        "13/10",
        "6/5"
    ]},

{
    "date": "2016-06-29",
    "item1": "5/4",
    "item2": [
        "9/10",
        "1"
    ],
    ]}}
```

I want to iterate through each of the entries in "results" convert the fractions into implied percentages and then create a new list in the same format as the original with the updated values.

I've created the following function in python to convert for one item in results:

```
item = results[0]["item1"]

emptyList = []  

def convertOdds():
    for i in item1:
        if "/" in i:

            winnings = int(i.rsplit("/", 1)[0])
            stake = int(i.rsplit("/", 1)[1])
            total = winnings + stake
            i = float((stake/total)*100)
            emptyList.append(round(i,2))    

    else:

            winnings = int(i)
            stake = 1
            total = winnings + stake
            i = float((stake/total)*100)
            emptyList.append(round(i,2))
```

But how would I go about calling that for each record in "results"?

My thinking is that I would need to call `convertOdds` for each item, so creating another function to go through the list call convertOdds() for each item and then create the list within that function?

But I'm at a loss on how to do this. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two '}' , you wrongly placed them. It's actually not a list.By the way, what is rsplit? I think you should use just split.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that only `item1` and `item2` keys have list of floats or ints, you can try this:

```
list_ = []

for dicts in results:
   item_1 = dicts["item1"]
   // pass item_1 in the method, append to list_
   item_2 = dicts["item2"]
   // pass item_2 in the method, list_ is updated

print list_
```

Answer (score 0):

The last part is the key to the solution.  You'll need to have access to both the key and the value in the dict key:value pair in order to test the key for 'item' and perform something on the value if it matches.  Hopefully this solves the problem, or at least points you in the right direction.

```
results = [
    {
        "date": "2016-06-30",
        "item1": [
            "9/2",
            "4",
        ],
        "item2": [
            "13/10",
            "6/5"
        ]},

    {
        "date": "2016-06-29",
        "item1": "5/4",
        "item2": [
            "9/10",
            "1"
        ]}
    ]


item = results[0]

emptyList = []


def convertOdds(i):
    for x in i:
        if "/" in x:

            winnings = int(x.rsplit("/", 1)[0])
            stake = int(x.rsplit("/", 1)[1])
            total = winnings + stake
            i = float((stake/total)*100)
            emptyList.append(round(i,2))

        else:

            winnings = int(x)
            stake = 1
            total = winnings + stake
            i = float((stake/total)*100)
            emptyList.append(round(i,2))


for k, v in item.items():
    if 'item' in k:
        convertOdds(v)
    else:
        pass

print(emptyList)
```

Output:

```
[43.48, 45.45, 18.18, 20.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given these revision to the op:

```
results = [
  {
    "date": "2016-06-30",
    "item1": [
        "9/2",
        "4",
    ],
    "item2": [
        "13/10",
        "6/5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-06-29",
    "item1": "5/4",
    "item2": [
        "9/10",
        "1"
    ]
  }
]
# cleaned up original results syntax only,
# note that item1 of the second record is a string.

def convert_odds(item_list):
  """ now takes the item_list as a variable
      returns the transform as a new_list
      *typecast total as a float
  """
  new_list = list()

  for i in item_list:

    if "/" in i:
      winnings = int(i.rsplit("/", 1)[0])
      stake = int(i.rsplit("/", 1)[1])
      total = float(winnings + stake) #*
      i = float((stake/total)*100)
      new_list.append(round(i,2))

    else:
      winnings = int(i)
      stake = 1
      total = float(winnings + stake) #*
      i = float((stake/total)*100)
      new_list.append(round(i,2))

  return new_list
```

---

The following will iterate over the results and convert odds in place...

```
def transform(original_list):
  new_list = list()

  for record in original_list:
    for key in record.keys():

      if 'item' in key:
        item = record.get(key)
        # normalize all items as list objects
        item_list = [item] if not isinstance(item, list) else item

        # call for odds conversion and update the record
        record.update({key:convert_odds(item_list)})

    new_list.append(record)
  return new_list
```

---

Calling transform will produce the following result...

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(transform(results))

[{'date': '2016-06-30', 'item1': [18.18, 20.0], 'item2': [43.48, 45.45]},
{'date': '2016-06-29', 'item1': [44.44], 'item2': [52.63, 50.0]}]
```